# How to make some of the Column lines Bold in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping

I have 36 columns in a table report,I need to make bold lines for every 3 columns.I tried Border style Solid and Double but still i could not make the changes.What should be done to make the lines bold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing your border width to 2pt? If you just type a 2 in the property it should work.

Since you are trying to make the columns bold, just try change the left and right borders, not the default. You will have to play around a little, because technically the borders of the columns on either side impact how the column looks.